# How to append a .crt file to .pem in windows CLI?

Tags: python, ssl, pip, python-requests, command-line-interface

I face SSL certificate issue using requests library in python.
The issue is that I need to use another certificate in addition to those provided by certifi package.

Of course I can basically append it using manual copy/paste at the bottom of the other.

However, I'd like to be able to do it using a one liner in windows CLI.

I tried :

```
copy $(pip config get global.cert)+$(python -m certifi) $(python -m certifi)
```

This one didn't work at all because copy can't output to the same file

```
type $(pip config get global.cert)>>$(python -m certifi)
```

This worked partially. Appending yes but the last cert was full of strange characters.

```
TYPE $(cp $(pip config get global.cert) root-CA.pem)>>$(python -m certifi)
```

So I tried to convert my .crt to pem before appending but got the following error : "Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null."

Does anybody have an idea how to solve it?
Many thanks

Sid

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround using a .bat file which first stores the two paths in variables and then perform the append in the first file.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f %%p in ('python -m certifi') do SET CERTIFI_CERT=%%p
FOR /f %%p in ('pip config get global.cert') do SET ROOT_CA=%%p
COPY /b %CERTIFI_CERT% + %ROOT_CA% %CERTIFI_CERT%
```

It does the job, even if I was looking for a one liner.
Feel free to propose if you know a simpler way to do it.

Sid